# Getting SEVERE: Could not locate SessionFactory in JNDI while getting sessionfactory

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, eclipse-plugin, hbm2java

I am using hibernate as persistence layer to communicate with the database. I used maven plugin hbm2java to generate dao, java, *hbm.xml and hibernate.cfg.xml. till that time plugins works fine.

But when I trying to communicate to db it gives following exception.

```
Aug 30, 2012 1:45:46 PM org.hbm2dao.AssemblyHome getSessionFactory
SEVERE: Could not locate SessionFactory in JNDI
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:     java.naming.factory.initial
at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(Unknown Source)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
at org.hbm2dao.AssemblyHome.getSessionFactory(AssemblyHome.java:29)
at org.hbm2dao.AssemblyHome.<init>(AssemblyHome.java:24)
at com.myhadoop.app.App.main(App.java:22)
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not locate SessionFactory in JNDI
at org.hbm2dao.AssemblyHome.getSessionFactory(AssemblyHome.java:33)
at org.hbm2dao.AssemblyHome.<init>(AssemblyHome.java:24)
at com.myhadoop.app.App.main(App.java:22)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.myhadoop.app.App.main(App.java:32)
```

by default hibernate3:hbm2cfgxml generates hibernate.cfg.xml file with session-factory name as SessionFactory. just like following.

```
<session-factory name="SessionFactory">
```

plugin generate following code to get session factory.

```
private final SessionFactory sessionFactory = getSessionFactory();

protected SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    try {

        return (SessionFactory) new InitialContext().lookup("SessionFactory");
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Could not locate SessionFactory in JNDI", e);
        throw new IllegalStateException("Could not locate SessionFactory in JNDI");
    }
}
```

I found similar query [Problems using eclipse Hibernate plugin - could not locate sessionfactory in JNDI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620612/problems-using-eclipse-hibernate-plugin-could-not-locate-sessionfactory-in-jnd).

However it not feasible to change 400+ classes generated by plugin to get session factory from *Home.java.

How to get rid of this problem with the hibernate plugin without changing 400+ classes?

I do not want to use any web/app server this is my standalone application.

Comment: Here is an answer I posted to a similar question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16380304/java-lang-illegalstateexception-could-not-locate-sessionfactory-in-jndi/16435578#16435578

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using that generated `getSessionFactory()` method will only work if you have set up your environment such that `InitialContext` can find your `hibernate.cfg.xml` file, and it sounds like it can't.

You can fix that problem by setting up `InitialContext` and your environment correctly as per the [`InitialContext` javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/naming/InitialContext.html).  As an alternative, you can cut out JNDI entirely by changing the `getSessionFactory` method to simply create a [`Configuration`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.html), and telling it where the mapping file(s) are.