# Could not locate SessionFactory in JNDI

Tags: hibernate, jndi, sessionfactory

I know you'll be mad at me.but I'll ask anyway.
i tried to every solution in stackoverflow for problem.but unresolved.
i generate to hibernate dao pojos and hbm.xml.and when i try to add something with dao,i am getting error "Could not locate SessionFactory in JNDI".***

**KullanicilarHome.java**

```
public class KullanicilarHome {

    private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(KullanicilarHome.class);
    private final SessionFactory sessionFactory = getSessionFactory();

    protected SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        try {
            return (SessionFactory) new InitialContext()
                    .lookup("SessionFactory");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Could not locate SessionFactory in JNDI", e);
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "Could not locate SessionFactory in JNDI");
        }
    }

    public void persist(Kullanicilar transientInstance) {
        log.debug("persisting Kullanicilar instance");
        try {
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().persist(transientInstance);
            log.debug("persist successful");
        } catch (RuntimeException re) {
            log.error("persist failed", re);
            throw re;
        }
    }
```

***and MainClass.java (test)***

```
public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Kullanicilar user = new Kullanicilar();
        user.setAd("Ergin");
        user.setSoyad("DURAN");
        user.setUniversite("Kxxx");
        user.setBolum("bxx");
        user.setCepTel("5xxxxxx");
        user.setEmail("exxxx");
        user.setVeliTel("55xxxxx");
        KullanicilarHome x = new KullanicilarHome();
        x.persist(user);

    }
```

***and hbm.cfg.xml***

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory name="SessionFactory">
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.session_factory_name">SessionFactory</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

***and tomcat version: v7.0.50
i say again Before you start to get angry. i tried to all solutions in stackoverflow.but did not work.***
    ->[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16380304/java-lang-illegalstateexception-could-not-locate-sessionfactory-in-jndi)
    ->[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12193917/getting-severe-could-not-locate-sessionfactory-in-jndi-while-geeting-sessionfac)
    ->[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12926398/could-not-locate-sessionfactory-in-jndi-with-hibernate-in-jetty-under-eclipse)
    ->[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620612/problems-using-eclipse-hibernate-plugin-could-not-locate-sessionfactory-in-jnd)

have a same problem and there solutions did not help me or did not understand there solutions.
help me please..
I apologize for my bad english
thanks***

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused between ejb and hibernate, I do not see where you are trying to set the sessionfactory into the JNDI. You have to do the following

```
public class KullanicilarHome {

private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(KullanicilarHome.class);
private final SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
.
.
.
.
```

Note: Make sure you have the .property file in the class path. Usually I put it in the WEB-INF folder.

Ref: [link](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/hibernate/create-hibernate-sessionfactory-example/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I do what they say.property and hbm.cfg.xml files on same directory.
src>main>java/mainclass & hibernate.properties  & hibernate.cfg.xml

and I am getting an error like:

http://codepaste.net/q3xyzt

Comment: If i put the files(properties and hbm.cfg.xml) into the web-inf,I'm getting "hibernate.cfg.xml" not found error

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18736594/location-of-hibernate-cfg-xml-in-project

Comment: thanks a lot.i can did it in the end.but in addition I had to do for each blabla.hbm.xml to add hibernate.cfg.xml and its very tiring.
thanks again